# Animation to expand from center to the edges, revealing parentView below

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have added a UIView (containing within it a UIVisualEffectView - blur) as a subview of another view. I would like to animate the subview from its center outwards towards the edges in a radial fashion, like an expanding circle. This should reveal its superView below.

Here is my code:

```
self.blurView =  [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, imageHeight)];
[superView addSubview: self.blurView];
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame = self.blurView.bounds;
[self.blurView addSubview:visualEffectButtonView];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
        //code with animation
        self.blurView.frame = CGRectMake(self.blurView.frame.origin.x, 
                    -self.blurView.frame.size.height, 
                    self.blurView.frame.size.width, 
                    self.blurView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //code for completion
        [self.blurView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

Comment: This animation is moving from down to upward as y position of blurView is becomes 0. How to do from centre to outward.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean from center outward? you mean to expand and become invisible?

Comment: I was looking for a radial animation for the blurView

Comment: I still did't quite get you, if you can link a video of a similar animation I'll be glad to do it!

Answer (score 0):

By Using     UIView Animation

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        delay:1.0
        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
            visualEffectView.alpha = 0;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [visualEffectView removeFromSuperview];
        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain the frame:

```
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
        delay:0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
        animations:^{
            viewToAnimate.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y);
            viewToAnimate.alpha = 0.0f;

        }completion:^(BOOL finished){

        }];
```

Move it in any direction you like using the x,y coordinates (x moves left and right, y moves up and down, in each case whether the value is negative or positive respectively), e.g. x = 10, moves the view 10 pixels to the right.

Comment: Thanks for respond but i have to do invisible the blurview from centre to outward radially.

Comment: change the .alpha value of the view to zero, see updated.

Comment: Do you want it to fade from the inside outwards? As in, the middle of the view goes invisible, and creeps towards the edges?

Comment: Yes subview will animate from inside to outward but it should not be fade. It should remove from middle and creeps towards the  edges of the superview so that superview will clearly visible.